# React Native Button absolute position not working on real iOS specific device

Tags: ios, react-native

I put a button in absolute position to on WebView.
This button works on any simulators and my iPhone 5s real device, but not work on iPhone Plus real device.
The button reacts when tapping, but doesn't fire onPress. It works when set position as relative.
All simulators and devices are same iOS version (12.2).

Does anyone know about this issue?

**Environments**
React Native 0.56
iOS 12.2

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, BackHandler, Keyboard, NetInfo, Platform, ScrollView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

export default class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    handleBackPress() {
        this.refs['WEBVIEW_REF'].goBack()
        return true
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" />
                <WebView
                    ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
                    bounces={false}
                    source={{ uri: 'https://example.com' }}
                    style={styles.container}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={this.handleBackPress.bind(this) }
                    buttonStyle={styles.buttonBack}
                    title=""
                    icon={{
                    name: 'chevron-left',
                    type: 'material-community',
                    iconStyle: { color: global.color.normal }
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonBack: {
        width: 45,
        height: 45,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 10,
        bottom: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
        opacity: 0.9
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 25,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Position absolute does not work properly in some cases at ios. you should wrap  in a :

```
<View style={{position:'absolute',...other styles}}>
<Button/> // without position style
<View>
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to this affirmation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding` on your button,it will solve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Dimensions` in this case. For example in your case you can use it like this:

```
buttonBack: {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width/100*10,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height/100*10,
  position: 'absolute',
  left: Dimensions.get('window').width/100*2,
  bottom: Dimensions.get('window').height/100*5,
  backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
  opacity: 0.9
},
```

> Dimensions.get('window').width/100*10 means 10 percent of total device
>   screen width and same for height.

Dimensions work as device specific. So it will take the same position according to Device Screen Height and Width.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by wrapping absolute position View.

```
  render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" />
                    <WebView
                        ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
                        bounces={false}
                        source={{ uri: 'https://example.com' }}
                        style={styles.container}
                    />
                   <View style={styles.navContainer}>
                        <Button
                           onPress={this.handleBackPress.bind(this) }
                           buttonStyle={styles.buttonBack}
                           title=""
                           icon={{
                               name: 'chevron-left',
                               type: 'material-community',
                               iconStyle: { color: global.color.normal }
                           }}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        buttonBack: {
            width: 45,
            height: 45,
            left: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
            opacity: 0.9
        },
        // moved from buttonBack style
        navContainer: {
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 60
        },
        //
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            paddingTop: 25,
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        },
    });
```